# How to Run Successfully UNFX Projects Using VSCode (Using the Source Code)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron, babeljs

All The Projects:

1. https://github.com/openproxyspace/unfx-proxy-checker
2. https://github.com/openproxyspace/unfx-proxy-to-country
3. https://github.com/openproxyspace/unfx-proxy-parser

I tried using "npm install" on first project and it gives an error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: unfx-proxy-checker@1.7.2
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   dev react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-hot-loader@4.13.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-hot-loader
npm ERR!   dev react-hot-loader@"^4.13.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

And after this, I just ignored this error, and I tried running "npm start" on first project, and it gave me this error:

```
'run-p' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `react-hot-loader` is [not compatible with React 18](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1808). If none of the other modules in your project require React 18 you could try manually downgrading your React version. You can do this by searching for the `react` and `react-dom` packages under `dependencies` (or `devDependencies`) in `package.json` and specifying the version `17.0.2`.

Otherwise maybe [React Fast Refresh could be a good alternative](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-fast-refresh-the-new-react-hot-reloader-652c6645548c) to `react-hot-loader`?

You can also try to ignore the error

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

by running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` and then fix the error

> 'run-p' is not recognized as an internal or external command

by manually installing the missing package: `npm i npm-run-all`

Comment: could you provide a video how to make [it](https://github.com/openproxyspace/unfx-proxy-checker) work?, i tried all of those steps you provided

Comment: or at least can you try to run it? and let me know what you did to make it work

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: windows 10 pro.